# userAccountControl property - delegate permission to set PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT

Tags: active-directory

I am needing to set the userAccountControl property of a user account to include TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION (0x1000000) and PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT (0x04000000).

To set TRUSTED_TO_AUTH_FOR_DELEGATION, the account performing the operation needs to be listed in the "Enable computer and user accounts to be trusted for delegation" setting in the security policy on the domain controller on which the operation is being performed. Once added in, the account can set that flag just fine.

However, setting PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT results in access denied for any account other than a domain admin.

My question, then, is can I delegate permission to set the PARTIAL_SECRETS_ACCOUNT flag on an account?